# fancyhdr - Only show sections, not subsections

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Is there a way for the header to only print the title of the parent section? So in the example below, the subsection{LOL} page will have "1.1 LOL" written in the header. I just want it to say "Introduction" which is the parent section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyhf{}

\rhead{\fancyplain{}{MyName}} % predefined ()
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }} % 1. sectionname
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\subsection{LOL}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either you also redefine `\subsectionmark` or use the `\leftmark`; in article type classes, `\subsection` emits a `\markright` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{MyName} % predefined ()
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\subsection{LOL}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also the "modern" `fancyhdr` syntax that avoids `\fancyplain`.

Comment: Perfect, I'll now have a go at understanding what you've done

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
```

With this redefinition, when you enter a subsection, it won't update the header, so the header will continue to show the title of the current section. This is useful if you want a consistent header throughout the section, regardless of subsections.