# (Warsaw Theme) How can I put the logo on the top right of each slide?

Tags: beamer, positioning, logos

Hi I wish that my logo could be on the top right of each slide and also to position it wherever I want on the title page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Rightarrowtext}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\text{#1}}{\Rightarrow}}}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\author{Philippe Fanaro}
\title{MC Algorithm for Non-Linear Equations}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Minerva}\vspace{175pt}}
%\institute{} 
\date{October 2014} 
%\subject{} 

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{
  \oldmacro\hfill
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}
```

This is what I have so far, I wish the logo would be on the top right blue part of the Warsaw theme, but no matter what I do with the "175pt" the image will not get there. I don't think the Warsaw theme enables it, maybe I'll have to write a custom theme.

[image: This is what I have so far, my logo won't get to where I want.]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc. What class are using you for these slides?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. An MWE is badly needed here. We do not even know which of the many possible classes and packages you are using to create your slides. (If you are using `beamer`, it depends heavily on your configuration. I have code to put a logo at the top right of slides but I doubt it would work for you.)

Comment: Does [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and graphicx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/how-do-i-add-an-image-in-the-upper-left-hand-corner-using-tikz-and-graphicx) answer your question?

Comment: I'm testing it but I was hoping for something simpler than that...

Comment: My trick works well but won't work here as you have no headline, I think. (I put the image in the headline.) Maybe you could make it part of the invisible right sidebar which contains the navigation bar?

Comment: The everypage package leaves the cursor at the upper left corner before corrections.  Using \raisebox one can insert anything anywhere.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203234/is-it-possible-to-use-both-long-name-and-short-name-of-the-section-in-headers/203380#203380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the image to the headline:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\subsection{blub1}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub3}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub4}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]