# Placement of logo in the default beamer theme

Tags: beamer, positioning

I follow [Logo on the top right of each slide in Warsaw theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262900/logo-on-the-top-right-of-each-slide-in-warsaw-theme) but the beamer default theme is different.

I would like to add a logo to each beamer slide in

- top right corner
- bottom right corner

I know I should redefine `beamertemplate{frametitle)` found in http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerouterthemedefault.sty

Where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**top right image**

You can tweak the vertical position by modifying the `\raisebox`, the horizontal position via the width of the `minipage`.

**bottom right corner**

use `\logo{...}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \begin{minipage}{.87\@tempdima}%
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
        {%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
          \else%
          {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
          \fi
        }%
        \vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
      \end{minipage}%
      \raisebox{-0.3cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]