# How to put logo in extreme right corner in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, logos

```
\documentclass[8pts]{beamer} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setbeamerfont{description}{size=\small}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\newcommand{\bcomma}{,\allowbreak}
\def\B(G){\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_G}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
%\usefonttheme{serif} this command is used for writting a good text font
%\mathcolor{blue}
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\title{International Conference on Analysis}  

%\logo{\includegraphics[width=1mm,height=1mm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}
\author[]{ {\bf Title: Minimizing spectral readius}\\\large{Presented by}\\{Joseph mor}}
\date{22 February, 2020}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}

%\logo{\includegraphics[width=1mm,height=1mm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}




\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: logo]

I am trying to put the logo symbol in the right corner below in each slide. But it is not coming. How to do this in beamer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just uncomment the line

```
\logo{\includegraphics[height=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}
```

the logo will appear in the right corner below. Compiling your code and uncommenting this line, I get

[image]

The logo is indeed a little small, but you can control its size with the `height` parameter in `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Does this suit your requirement

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\subsection{blub1}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub3}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{blub4}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Courtesy-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347635/197451